# ¿Por qué aparece hombres si el sexo es femenino?

Tags: sql

He puesto bien el código pero no entiendo por qué aparecen los nombres de empleados hombres si la pregunta solo me pide que sean empleadas mujeres (e.sex like 'f').

Éste es el código. Espero que me puedan ayudar:

```
 SELECT distinct d.departmentname Departamentos, e.GivenName
 FROM employees e, departments d
 where e.departmentid =d.departmentid and e.givenname like 'd%' or e.givenname 
 like 'j%'  and e.sex like 'f'
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask], si editas y colocas datos de prueba de tus tablas sería mas fácil apoyarte, además ¿qué motor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Un consejo, cuando haya varios condicionales **usa siempre los paréntedis** para determinar cómo deben hacerse las evaluaciones. También, pon las prioridades de forma descendente en la consulta, eso ayuda a entenderla y organizarla. Por ejemplo, si sólo debe traer los de sexo femenino, ese debería ser el primer criterio. Creo que así la consulta se entiende mejor y te traerá los datos esperados: `where (e.sex like 'f') and (e.departmentid = d.departmentid) and (e.givenname like 'd%' or e.givenname 
 like 'j%' )`. O sea: *los de sexo `f` Y del departamento `tal` Y los de givenname `d` O `j`*

Comment: Lo lamento mucho por no preguntar bien, soy bien novato muchas gracias por su ayuda quiero preguntar ¿esos paréntesis  son como matemáticas osea primero debe leer lo que están dentro de los paréntesis y así hacia afuera verdad?

Comment: Correcto, matemáticas o lógica. Ten en cuenta que los `AND` y `OR` son comparaciones lógicas. Los paréntesis te blindan contra eventuales confusiones en el código, ayudan al manejador a saber cómo tiene que hacer las evaluaciones y al programador a entender mejor el código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esa consulta estas filtrando por (departamento `AND` givenname) `OR` (givenname `AND` sexo)

Si quieres que siempre sea sexo femenino seria asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.departmentname Departamentos, e.GivenName
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE e.departmentid = d.departmentid AND e.givenname LIKE 'd%' AND e.sex LIKE 'f'
OR e.departmentid = d.departmentid AND e.givenname LIKE 'j%' AND e.sex LIKE 'f'
```

Comment: Podrías simplificar el código un poco haciendo `WHERE e.departmentid = d.departmentid AND (e.givenname LIKE 'd%' OR e.givenname LIKE 'j%') AND e.sex LIKE 'f'`

Comment: Okey lo entiendo entonces debo tomar en cuenta con el OR muchas gracias, que triste que mi profe no enseño eso